# Sencha Touch application running very slow

Tags: sencha-touch

I have completed the UI for my application in Sencha Touch and has integrated every page.
But when i run the application it is terribly slow ( even without any functionalities- not even a database connection ). Any one knows how to make the application run faster ? Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What device or browser are you running on? Are you using the debug library or the one with comments in? Or the production, minified one? Also of course, it would be good to see the code & the sort of components you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Without much code, it's hard to tell what exactly the problem will be. That said, there's numerous common causes of slow performance:

- DOM goes too deep
- Not destroying panels after you're finished with them
- Using intensive animations on older/slower phones
- autoLoading all your data on app initialization, rather than lazy-loading them when the appropriate panel opens

I'd highly recommend if you haven't checked it out already, [to watch this video on Sencha Touch optimization](http://www.senchatouchbits.com/10/performance-optimization.html). There's a slideshare out there of it too, though less detailed. This is just the beginning though -- mobile devices have less memory and CPU power so elegant and efficient code is the best medicine. I would follow up watching that video with reading up about [building your app in an MVC architecture](http://myxaab.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/sencha-touch-mvc-application-part-2/).

Answer (score 0):

View [here](http://www.swarmonline.com/2011/05/20-things-to-avoid-or-do-when-getting-started-with-extjs-and-sencha-touch/). Hope this helps.